# Matrix value not being interpreted in `uses` within a caller yaml

Tags: github-actions

I have a workflow that calls other workflows. [Docs](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/reusing-workflows).

My yaml looks like:

```
jobs:
  update-daily-tables:
    strategy:
      matrix:
        workflow: [update-apples, update-pears, update-peaches]
    uses: ./.github/workflows/${{ matrix.workflow }}.yaml
```

Results in error:

> error parsing called workflow "./.github/workflows/${{ matrix.workflow }}.yaml": failed to fetch workflow: workflow was not found.

Expected `uses` to be interpreted as one the 3 matrix values e.g:

```
./.github/workflows/update-apples.yaml
```

Why is my matrix value not being interpreted within uses and how can I achieve my desired result?

Comment: The problem here is that the **github interpreter** check the workflow before starting the runner. In that case, it can't identify a valid value for the workflow file (as the matrix hasn't been created yet) and that's the reason why it returns an error and that it's not possible to use matrix variables that way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This `${{ matrix.workflow }}` is known on runtime, and your workflow must be valid at compile time, which means before your workflow will be triggered.

Your only option would be to parametrise a reusable workflow and pass the value of the matrix as a parameter and put it inside conditional logic.

```
jobs:
  update-daily-tables:
    strategy:
      matrix:
        workflow: [update-apples, update-pears, update-peaches]
    uses: ./.github/workflows/update.yaml
    with:
      target: ${{ matrix.workflow }}
```